# Free Source Code Repository in Spanish

Tags: version-control, localization

I'm looking for an online source code repository that is available in Spanish. I have some experience with BitBucket and GitHub, but it doesn't appear that either of their websites is localized into Spanish. The only sites that I've found that work in Spanish are paid, which is a non-starter since I'm on a Peace Corps budget.

Background: I'm working with a group of students at a university in Paraguay, and as part of the project I want to teach them good development practices such as using source control and issue tracking systems. However, they don't all have strong English abilities, so it will be difficult to use anything that isn't available in their native language.

Does anybody have a suggestion of a good hosted source control system whose site is localized into Spanish?

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket just launched beta translations, and the Spanish translation looks fairly decent, so that's what I'll be using.